# How to get the link from the server when the download button is clicked using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get the link from the server when the download button is clicked.

Html in view-source:

```
    <div class="limit_down">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="down_t" onclick="env.downloadVideo(35678);return false;">
        <i class="iconfont icon-download-"></i>
        Download
      </a>
    </div>
```

I'm using Selenium Chrome in Python.

Please just help me. Thanks

Comment: maybe first get link manually and check its structure - if it has number `35678` like in `env.downloadVideo(35678)` then maybe you could generate next links without clicking button.

Comment: I used IDM Download and got the URL like this:

https://proxy-vip.lovepik.rice/vfiles/video/17/47/86/a_edtaRIM2gJQv1548174786.mov

Comment: if you would show URL for this page then we could search this link in HTML or in JavaScript data, or in AJAX requests to server.

Comment: How do you do it ?

Comment: I open HTML in text edito and use function `find` to search ie. `proxy-vip.lovepik.rice/vfiles/`. Sometimes I do the same with JavaScript file. But mainly I use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox (tab: Network) to see all reuqest send to server - and I check what data it gets from server. Often JavaScript/AJAX reads data from server